# How to add a WHERE clause to BigQuery Query to find rows where a column value is not in a list of values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery named events that has a column named 'entitlement'.  That column can have values such as 'lapb', 'lacf', 'lasg', 'laxy', 'laza' etc.  It can also have 'null' or '' or other values that I don't know.  It will only have 1 given value per row so it isn't a list of values.  So for example, here is some sample data:

```
name    entitlement date
alice   laxy        01072017
bob     null        01082018
charlie lapb        01092017
daniel  lacf        01092017
```

etc

How can I write a query so that I can check if the entitlement value is not in a list of values?

This is how I am currently doing it.  I am adding an additional "and entitlement != clause for each one.

```
SELECT *
FROM events 
WHERE entitlement != 'lapb' and entitlement != 'lacf' 
and entitlement != 'lasg' and entitlement != 'laxy' 
and entitlement != 'laza' and entitlement is not null
order by logtime desc
LIMIT 1000
```

I tried doing the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM events 
WHERE entitlement is not in ['labp', 'lpaf']
order by logtime desc
LIMIT 1000
```

but I get the following error:

Query Failed
Error: Encountered "" at line 3, column 33.

Is there a way in BigQuery to check for only rows that do not contain values in a list or must I add an individual "and entitlement != ..." clause for each additional value?  Basically the query is really becoming large and complicated very quickly and I was trying to find a way to simplify it for manageability and readability purposes.  I tried square brackets, parentheses, nothing, etc but all give me the same error.

Comment: Did you try `entitlement not in ('labp', 'lpaf')`?

Comment: Yes, it generates the same error above that is why I said I tried square brackets, parentheses, nothing, etc but all give me the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
WITH events AS (
  SELECT 'alice' AS name, 'laxy' AS entitlement, '01072017' AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bob', NULL, '01082018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'charlie', 'lapb', '01092017' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'daniel', 'lacf', '01092017'
)
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE entitlement NOT IN ('labp', 'lpaf');
+---------+-------------+----------+
| name    | entitlement | date     |
+---------+-------------+----------+
| alice   | laxy        | 01072017 |
| charlie | lapb        | 01092017 |
| daniel  | lacf        | 01092017 |
+---------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: This is actually what I am looking for.  So to recap I needed the following form your answer: 1) "#standardSQL" before the query,  2) "NOT IN" instead of "IS NOT IN", 3) parenthesis instead of square brackets for the list of possible values.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH events AS (
  SELECT 'alice' AS name, 'laxy' AS entitlement, '01072017' AS DATE UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bob', NULL, '01082018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mike', '', '01082018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'charlie', 'lapb', '01092017' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'dan', 'n/a', '01082018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'daniel', 'lacf', '01092017'
), known_entitlements AS (
  SELECT entitlement 
  FROM UNNEST(['laxy','lapb','lacf']) entitlement
)
SELECT e.*
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN known_entitlements k
ON e.entitlement = k.entitlement
WHERE k.entitlement IS NULL
```

You can add all known entitlements into `known_entitlements` or you can just have all in separate table

result is

```sql
name    entitlement date     
bob     null        01082018     
mike                01082018     
dan     n/a         01082018
```

Comment: The thing is I don't know the actual entitlements.  I am using a very large production BigQuery database from "https://bigquery.cloud.google.com".  The entitlements are populated into the data from a 3rd party and I literally have millions of records.  I am trying to scrub the data to make sure that we behave correctly for some entitlements and then capturing the ones that don't match for further investigation.

Comment: this does not match to how you asked your question  - so you might want to clarify what exactly you need! You question was relativelly clear - `How can I write a query so that I can check if the entitlement value is not in a list of values?` - but now i don't understand what exactly you ask!

Comment: Mikhail, I was basically trying to eliminate the rows that had the known entitlements but I also wanted to be able to extend the list of values to exclude easily as I encountered more values.  In all, I have now seen at least 15 different entitlements and I am still parsing records.  Basically this table has millions of rows and it is constantly getting more.  I wish I could explain it more clearly than I did but I am not sure what else needed to be said.

Comment: so, that is exactly what query in my answer does! I recommend to read it more to get it :o)

Comment: I tried to run your code but with the size of the database the join operation is taking a very long time to run.  I appreciate that you took the time to respond but I think Elliott Brossard's answer was more concise and easier for me to understand.  If I have more time in the future, I will investigate your response further.

Comment: sure, no problem. i was not worry about whose answer you accepts  - this is not that important really. just wanted to make sure you are not missing something that can help in future